# ElasticSearch count terms from two fields (aggregation)

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, aggregation

I am trying to create a word cloud by using two fields from ElasticSearch index.

My current code:

```
var excludeWords = [
  'on', 'in', 'the', 'a', 'at'
];

client.search({
  index: indexName,
  type: "item",
  searchType: "count",
  body: {
    "query": {"match_all": {}},
    "aggs": {
      "description_words": {
        "terms": {
          "field": "description",
          "exclude": excludeWords,
          "size": 100
        }
      },
      "summary_words": {
        "terms": {
          "field": "summary",
          "exclude": excludeWords,
          "size": 100
        }
      }
    }
  }
}).then(function (resp) {
  res.json(resp);
}, function (err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```

With this code I am getting back two aggregation results description_words and summary_words and word counts.

Is it possible to combine those results using ES aggregation so in case description_words aggregation has word "dog" 10 times and summary_words has "dog" 2 times then it will give me one combined aggregation where "dog" count is 12?

Second thing - I needed to remove my nGram analysers from summary and description fields for the code above to work summary.raw and description.raw magic didn't work for some reasons. Any suggestions?